# EHCACHE disk allocation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, file, ehcache

I was going through the `EHCACHE` implementation how they do the disk allocation.

It first serializes the `Element` to Byte array than it calls for a space by calling the method:`allocator.alloc(size)`

WHERE `size` is the size of the byte array.

Here `allocator` is the instance of [**`FileAllocationTree`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.1/net/sf/ehcache/store/compound/factories/FileAllocationTree.java) so my doubt is how `FileAllocationTree` allocates a free region from the file and i observe that they are using [**`AATree`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.1/net/sf/ehcache/store/compound/factories/AATreeSet.java#AATreeSet) for free space management, hence how they are segregating the space in the Tree.

**EDIT**

I WILL make my question more specific: want to know how `ehcache` manages free spaces by the AA tree which is implemented by the class [`AATreeSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.8/net/sf/ehcache/store/compound/factories/AATreeSet.java)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can know that the AA tree is a simplified form of a red-black tree (a self-balancing binary search tree), please see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree).

> A red-black tree need to consider **seven** different shapes to properly balance the tree.

while

> An AA tree on the other hand only needs to consider **two** shapes due to the strict requirement that only right links can be red.

Here we need to manage our free space by using a self-balancing binary search tree, helping us insert, delete, and search (max, min, and some proper) free space.

I believe that there is no special reason EHCACHE uses AA tree sets to manage the free space. They just need a self-balancing binary search tree and they choose the one easy to implement. We may see both FileAllocationTree and AATreeSet have similar methods like "insert", "delete", and "search".

EHCACHE uses a self balancing BST to take the advantages of its average high performance of inserting, deleting, and searching, **where each node of this BST represents a range of free space and the node's value represent the size of free space**. Yet I don't have the statistics to prove this high performance. I believe it may be better than a hash table (on upper/lower bound search) and a native binary tree (on self balancing).

By the way, a self-balancing binary search tree is used to manage **memory** space, while a [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) is usually used to manage **disk** space (filesystem and database), due to its high fanout and cheap iteration on leaves.

Comment: you did not answer the question. OP asked **how they are managing space by the self balancing tree**.

Comment: @Trying It may be straight forward to see how. EHCACHE uses a self balancing BST to take the advantages of its average high performance of inserting, deleting, and searching, where each node of this BST represents a range of free space and the node's value represent the size of free space. Yet I don't have the statistics to prove this high performance. I believe it may be better than a hash table (on upper/lower bound) and a native binary tree (on self balancing).

Comment: @matthew lewis May you review my answer and give some feedback please.

Comment: @TaoHE Could you please clarify how do they use BST if elements with the same priority are not allowed in such structures?